# How do I pass an array as a parameter?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

This is driving me crazy:

I have function

```
void gst_init(int *argc, char **argv[]);
```

in the gstreamer api and I want to call it with some parameters I define, like:

```
int argc = 2;
char* argv[2] = {"myvalue1", "myvalue2"};
gst_init(&argc, &argv);
```

This code doesn't compile (I get error C2664):

```
error C2664: 'gst_init' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'char *(*)[2]' to 'char **[]'
```

**The question**: *How do I define the `argv` value to pass it as a parameter?* I've been using C++ for over 5 years, but I haven't used a raw array since ... high-school I think (more than five years ago).

**Edit**: I'm using VS2010 Express.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
int argc = 2;
char* arg1[1] = {"myvalue1"};
char* arg2[1] = {"myvalue2"};
char** argv[2] = { arg1, arg2 };
gst_init(&argc, argv);
```

`char **argv[]` is an array of `char**`, which is analogous to an array of `char*` arrays.

OTOH what you tried to pass as parameter is shown as `char *(*)[2]`: a pointer to an array of `char*`.

Comment: doesn't work: `error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const char [9]' to 'char **'`

Comment: -1 don't do that. gst_init takes pointers so it can 'remove' the arguments from the command line which it processes by modifying *argc and *argv.

Comment: so what should he do instead? I had a similar feeling and the OP tried a similar solution, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 5):

Normally you would follow the instructions in the [manual](http://www.gstreamer.net/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/chapter-init.html), and pass pointers to the arguments provided by `main`, so that gstreamer can remove the arguments which it handles.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gst/gst.h>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    gst_init (&argc, &argv);
    // handle the remaining argc values of argv
```

If you want to create your own arguments, then create the same sort of array which `main` would have:

```
void gst_init(int *argc, char **argv[])
{
    // strip one argument
    --*argc;
    ++*argv;
}

void foo ()
{
    int argc = 2;

    char* args[] = {"myvalue1", "myvalue2"};
    char** argv = args;

    for(int i= 0; i < argc; ++i)
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);

    gst_init(&argc, &argv);

    for(int i= 0; i < argc; ++i)
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
}
```

If you're not using C99, it's easier to have a separate pointer to the local array of string literals. Using C99, you could just write `char** argv = (char*[]){"myvalue1", "myvalue2"};` to start with a pointer to the first element in an anonymous array.

You need to pass a pointer to a variable pointing to the array rather than a pointer to the first element in the array; in the first case the degradation of an array parameter to a pointer achieves the same effect as the second case declaring a pointer local variable - you then can pass the address of this variable and the function can modify it. sizeof( args) is 8 on a 32bit machine as the compiler deduces the number of elements in the array; sizeof(argv) is 4, therefore ++args would move the pointer to the end of the array rather than to the next element as ++argv does. The compiler protects you from such an operation.

But normally you'd use it in the way the manual suggests.

Comment: I know I should pass the args and argv -- I was just curious on how to manually define the parameters (that is why I didn't tag the question "gstreamer" - I was just interested in the syntax). 

Thanks for the answer though (I got something else from it).

Have a +1 :)