# How to assign values to argc and argv in code and pass them to gst_init()

Tags: qt, gstreamer

I want to declare and assign values to argc and argv in code rather than main function, so how to do that? I am using Qt.

Comment: if you dont want to pass any arguments , gst_init(NULL, NULL);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// Works but wherever you use argv you should use * with it.
int argc = 2;
char* arg1[1] = {"gstreamer"}; // Program Name
char* arg2[1] = {"/home/1.ogg"};
char** argv[2] = { arg1 , arg2};
```

Another Method:

```
// Works without any need for *
char  arg0[] = "gstreamer"; // Program Name
char  arg1[] = "/home/1.ogg";
char* argv[] = { &arg0[0], &arg1[0], NULL };
int   argc   = (int)(sizeof(argv) / sizeof(argv[0])) - 1;
```

References:

[How do I pass an array as a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093116/how-do-i-pass-an-array-as-a-parameter)

[Defining own main functions arguments argc and argv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519885/defining-own-main-functions-arguments-argc-and-argv/1519997#1519997)